# Placeholder in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, placeholder

I have tired a few placeholder plugins to get it to work in IE. Currently I'm using http://widgetulous.com/placeholderjs/. This works in IE8 & 9 but not IE7. It throws a SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
placeholder.js, line 182 character 5
SCRIPT5009: 'Placeholder' is undefined 
csr-form.html, line 72 character 3 - This is where I call the placeholder.js via:

```
$(function(){
    // Placeholder
    Placeholder.init();
});
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work in IE7 or can someone suggest another plugin that works in IE7?

**UPDATED**
Here is the fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/NLWRL/

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more context? How is that script included on the page and where is it in relation to the Placeholder.js include?

Comment: Hi' it's an internal project but i'll try create a mockup on jsfiddle, cheers

Comment: I'd just like to see your `<script>` tags, how they're ordered, and where they're included within the HTML.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I created a quick mockup, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/NLWRL/ Cheers

Comment: In this case, I see that `Placeholder.init();` comes after the Placeholder.js script. Can you verify the issue still exists in IE7 when Placeholder.js is loaded before the `Placeholder.init();` call?

Comment: Hi, yes it still does the same thing if I change the order :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ah, your problem is a **trailing comma** in a hash like this

```
{
 'this':'blows',
 'up': 'ie7',
}
```

**edit**: yep i see it, your `utils` hash in that fiddle has a trailing comma after it.

here is **the fix**: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NLWRL/1/

not tested in ie7, there might be more trailing commas hiding in there for you to find

by the way when you see `Expected identifier, string or number` in ie7, 9/10 times its a trailing comma.

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem with placeholder.js version 1.1. Just remove the trailing commas at line 182 and 229.

Comment: Just a heads up for Googlers, thanks to this thread, placeholder.js version 1.1.1 incorporates the ie7 fix.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using [Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin by mathiasbynens](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin) at work.

It says IE6+ is supported, and we haven't had any troubles with IE7.

Usage is nice — set the placeholder attribute in your input tags and call `$('input').placeholder();` in your `$(function())`

Comment: In IE7 I get an input resize when I blur out of the field